# Xamarin remove storyboard

Tags: xamarin, xib

I followed tutorial to create mvvmcross solution. All works well, but I notice there is FirstView (with xib/cs/designer.cs) and also there is Storyboard. How can I remove the storyboard and use purely xibs on this project?

I tried deleted the Main.storyboard and ViewController.cs/designer.cs but that just crash the app and not loading the FirstView at all. Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the Storyboard you need to also update the `info.Plist` file.

Remove the text `Main` from the **Main Interface**

[image: info.plist]

Now you will need to update the AppDelegate of your app to set your ViewController as the RootViewController (the ViewController the App will call when it finished loading).

To make this update your `FinishedLaunching` method with code like this:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    Window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
    Window.RootViewController = new YourViewController ();
    Window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

    return true;
}
```

This should work.

Comment: The Main name in Main Interface was the problem. My appdelegate is different a bit because I use MvxAppDelegate. But anyhow it works now thanks.!